# C++ Switch statement loop back to menu

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, do-while

I'm struggling to get my switch statement to go back to the start after an option is selected, to allow the user to input another option. I removed all the code from the switch cases just to cut it down a bit.

Thanks

```
int main() {
    char tab = '\t';

    int input;
    bool menu = true;


    FlightSystem f;
    vector <Aircraft> allAircraftList_{};

    std::string flightNumber, airline, aircraftType, gridReference;
    int groundSpeed, altitude, heading;

    const int MaxAlt = 60000, MinAlt = 0, MaxSpeed = 800, MinHeading = 0, MaxHeading = 360;

    regex fNumber{ "([a-z]{2}([a-z])?[0-9]([0-9])?([0-9])?([0-9])?([0-9])?)" };

    do {
        std::cout << "#########################################################" << endl;
        std::cout << "#Flight Control Simulation#" << endl;
        std::cout << "#########################################################" << endl;
        std::cout << "" << endl;

        std::cout << tab << "1. Add Aircraft" << endl;
        std::cout << tab << "2. List All Aircraft" << endl;
        std::cout << tab << "3. List All Cruising Aircraft" << endl;
        std::cout << tab << "4. Number of Aircrafts in Sector" << endl;
        std::cout << tab << "5. Remove Aircraft" << endl;
        std::cout << tab << "6. Change Heading" << endl;
        std::cout << tab << "7. Get Heading" << endl;
        std::cout << tab << "8. Change Altitude" << endl;
        std::cout << tab << "9. Get Altitude" << endl;

        std::cout << "" << endl;
        std::cout << "---------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

        std::cout << "Please enter an option, between 1-9:" << endl;

        std::cin >> input;

        switch (input) {
        case:
             break;
        default:
            cout << "Your selection must be between 1 and 9" << endl;

        }
        return 0;
    } while (input != 9);
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning there? That will end execution immediately. Just remove the return and it looks like it will work.

Comment: `case:
         break;` Does that even compile?

Comment: wow..... that was stupid. Thanks lol

Comment: a Carcigenicate said, after the first input from the user you will return.. Second this will not compile as your case statement has no value for input. you need to have a case for each menu item case 1: case 2: etc... with the default doing nothing. Also you need to handle if/when the user types something that is NOT a integer. In that case input will not be set but cin will have reported a failure. If I remember correctly (its been a few years).

Comment: move return after `while (input != 9);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my advice. Use a while loop. do-while loop in this case is unnecessary.

here's how it can be used (i made a simple program that enters a number, you can modify it accordingly, just replace my code with your switch statements)

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
{
int x;
bool repeat = true;
while(repeat)
{
    cout<<"enter a number"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    cout<<"do you want to enter another number (y/n)"<<endl;
    char ch;
    cin>>ch;
    if(ch=='y'||ch =='Y')
        continue;
    else
        repeat = false;
}
cout<<"you entered "<<x;
}
```